# Error generating the API metadata for Cloud Endpoints classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-eclipse-plugin

I have two different cloud endpoint methods with two different name signatures

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getWhiteCats", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
 public CollectionResponse<Cat> getWhiteCats(CatCall request)
```

And

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getGrayCats", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public CollectionResponse<Cat> getGrayCats(CatCall request)
```

But Eclipse is giving the exception

> Description   Resource    Location    Path    Type There was a problem generating
>   the API metadata for your Cloud Endpoints classes:
>   com.google.api.server.spi.config.validation.DuplicateRestPathException:
>   Multiple methods with same rest path "POST
>   collectionresponse_cat":"getWhiteCats" and "getGrayCats"

Any thoughts on how I might resolve this issue?

Comment: I am looking to see if there is a way to specify the name of the returned value through annotation, but I don't see one.

Comment: I solve it by creating my own wrapper class for one of the methods.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by passing one more parameter in the @apiMethod annotation
for example in your case

@ApiMethod(name = "getWhiteCats", path="Somepath_realted_to_your_service", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a path for your methods with path = "yourPathHere". 
It should look something like this:

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getWhiteCats", path = "getWhiteCats", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
 public CollectionResponse getWhiteCats(CatCall request)
```

and

```
@ApiMethod(name = "getGrayCats", path = "getGrayCats", httpMethod = HttpMethod.POST)
public CollectionResponse getGrayCats(CatCall request)
```

The path doesn't have to be the name of your @ApiMethod but I highly recommend it.